# UserControl ComboBox not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, user-controls

I've created the **UserControl DefaultComboBox**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.ComboBoxes.DefaultComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxDefault"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DefaultItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The **CodeBehind of the ComboBox UserControl**:

```
public partial class DefaultComboBox : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<String> _defaultItems = new ObservableCollection<String>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> DefaultItems
    {
        get { return _defaultItems; }
        set
        {
            _defaultItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(DefaultItems);
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public DefaultComboBox()
    {
        UpdateList(ExternalSource.InitialItemList);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultItems");

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Some DependencProperties like Filter

    // Update Method
    private void UpdateList(List<String> newList)
    {
        DefaultItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(newList);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultItems");
    }
}
```

And here is an example of using the Control:

```
<comboBoxes:DefaultComboBox x:Name="DefaultComboBoxUserView"
                            Filter="{Binding FilterString}"/>
```

**The problem:**

If I start my WPF application for the first time and the constructor of DefaultComboBox is called, the UpdateList method works and the ComboBox contains the expected items.

If I use the UpdateList method at runtime, the setter of DefaultItems is called and the items have been correctly updated, but when I click in the GUI on the combo box drop-down, the old items are still there and nothing has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the value of _defaultItems. That's not what `Observable` in  `ObservableCollection` does. You should keep the collection `instance` the same at all times and only Add() and Remove() from it.

One way of entirely replacing the old collection with the new one would be:

```
// Update Method
private void UpdateList(List<String> newList)
{
    DefaultItems.Clear();
    DefaultItems.AddRange(newItems);
}
```

Note that this is inefficient and ObservableCollection will update view each time an item is added. There are ways around that, like suspending the notifications until AddRange is done.